# What is the meaning of {} braces in this variable declaration?

Tags: perl

I saw in some code a declaration like:

```
$test  = "test";
$test1 = "tes2";
$i     = 2;
$var{$test}{$test1}{"cnt"}[$i] = $var_val;    # What exactly is this?
```

If they mention the `{` brace, that is concatenation. I really not understand what this is.

My guess is that the final variable is like `$vartesttest1cnt2`.

Comment: See [Perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types): scalars, arrays and hashes.

Comment: also, `.` is concatenation. `($test . $test1)` is `"testtes2"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, no, not really. `%var` is a hash of hashes of hashes of arrays.

`%var` is a hash

`$var{$test}` => `$var{"test"}` is a hash

`$var{$test}{$test1}` => `$var{"test"}{"tes2"}` is a hash

`$var{$test}{$test1}{"cnt"}` => `$var{"test"}{"tes2"}{"cnt"}` is an array

`$var{$test}{$test1}{"cnt"}[$i]=$var_val` assigns `$var_val` to index 2 in the array

Comment: `%var` is a hash! `$var` is undefined :)

Comment: @Matt Kane, oops, fixed that.

Comment: You're being sloppy with terminology. `$var{"test"}` is not a hash. It's the *value* stored in the hash for the key "test". It could be any scalar. It isn't until we see `$var{$test}{...}` that we know that `$var{$test}` holds a hash *reference*.

Comment: And just to be pedantic `$var{'test'}` is a reference to a hash etc etc etc. You can do the assignment to the arrayref in this way due to the "arrow rule" in `perldoc perlreftut` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html (which is a great read for the OP).

Comment: @Michael Carman, you're right that I'm a bit sloppy. I just wanted to explain it as simply as possible to maximize understanding. You yourself are also being sloppy, because while `$var{$test}{...}` might indicate that the programmer thinks that it holds a hash reference, we wont know for sure until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

No, `%var` is a hash.

`test` is a key in the hash.

`$var{$test}` becomes `$var{"test"}` which then becomes whatever value is stored at that key, which was apparently another hash. Its key `$test1` leads to another hash, which has a key `cnt` which leads to an array, whose index `$i` (2) is set to `$var_val`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a multi-dimensional data structure. `%var` is a hash. `$var{$test}` is a hash element. `$var{$test}{$test1}` means that your hash element is a reference to another hash. `$var{$test}{$test1}{"cnt"}` means that `$var{$test}{$test1}` is itself a reference to a hash. `$var{$test}{$test1}{"cnt"}[$i]` means that the preceding level is a reference to an array. Don't understand what a reference is? [Try perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: Try `perldoc perlreftut` (the reference tutorial), `perldoc perldsc` (the data structures cookbook), and `perldoc perlref` (the full story on references in Perl)